# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut change image src

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am making an image map and have been trying to make images fade in and out in succession by changing the image source (this is important). Problem with the code below, is that it only uses the last source image and fades that in and out 5 times. I of course would like each image to fade in and out once. Brain may explode soon. Any idea what I am doing wrong. As you can tell, I am a noob at jQuery. Appreciate the help.

```
imgArray = Array(
  "img0.png",
  "img1.png",
  "img2.png",
  "img3.png",
  "img4.png"
);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  for(i=0; i<5; i++)
     jQuery('#imgHolder').attr('src', imgArray[i]).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).fadeOut('slow')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this somewhere on the internets and it did the trick:

`for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {`

`newPhoto = 'Image HTML';`

`jQuery("#id").fadeOut('fast').html(newPhoto).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn();`

}

I just couldn't get any of the other methods to work.

Answer (score 0):

I probably assume that you called all the images with the id `imgHolder` So every loop changed all the images' source to the last one.

You should do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#imgHolder').each(function(index) {
     $(this).attr('src',imgArray[index]).fadeIn('slow').delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
   });
});
```

Important note: try avoiding calling elements with the same `id`, the `id` attribute is supposed to be unique.

Comment: I am actually trying to use a single image element - changing the source of this element. I.e. there is only one element with `<img id="imgHolder" src="" />`

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn and fadeOut has callback function, like :

```
$("#imgHolder").fadeIn('slow', function(){
    //$(this) -> $("#imgHolder")
    //do something
})
```

//Do not use a for loop。

Comment: could not get this method to work recursively (still defaults to last img), however, if string this together as one ridiculously long line of code, it does work. Not going to close the question quite yet as I would like to see if another solution comes along.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you should use, setting a callback function on the fadeIn, to queue the fadeOut.

```
jQuery('#imgHolder').attr('src', imgArray[i]).fadeIn('slow', function(){
  $(this).delay(500).fadeOut('slow')
});
```

however something like

```
jQuery('#imgHolder').attr('src', imgArray[i]).fadeIn('slow', function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut('slow')
   },500)
});
```

might be more suitable. Up to you, really.

Comment: Missing a }, but still, functionality is not as desired. Loads fist image, the quickly removes it and sets last image. Wierd. Drupal issue?